# What is the smallest and the largest possible adjacency eigenvalue of a regular graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

For a $d$-regular graph I think $d$ is always the largest adjacency eigenvalue and if its bipartite then I think $-d$ is the smallest possible.

Comment: That your bounds are upper/lower bounds follows immediately from the Gerschgorin circle theorem, since each circle in a $d$-regular graph has radius $d$ and is centered at $0$. The question is whether they're attainable.

Comment: Your upper bound is easily attainable using the constant eigenvector.

Comment: In the bipartite case, try an eigenvector whose entries are $1$ on one part and $-1$ on the other.

Comment: @Ian By a constant eigenvector do you mean an eigenvector will all $1$s? And do you know proofs for the lowest and the highest bounds?

Answer (score 2):

If you consider a vector of all $1$s, then the matrix will map it to a vector of all $d$s. So $d$ can be attained as an eigenvalue. This is maximal by the Gerschgorin circle theorem, which tells you (among other things) that an eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ must be in a closed disk in the complex plane centered at $a_{ii}$ with radius $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1,j \neq i}^n |a_{ij}|$. For the adjacency matrix of a $d$-regular graph, $a_{ii} = 0$ and the radius is $d$.

In the bipartite case, if you consider a vector which is $1$ on one part and $-1$ on the other, then the adjacency matrix will switch the locations of the minus signs and then scale everything by $d$ again. So this will give you an eigenvalue of $-d$. Again the Gerschgorin circle theorem tells you this is the minimal possibility for any $d$-regular graph. Of course in the non-bipartite case the smallest eigenvalue is probably larger.

Comment: Definitely larger. $\lambda_{1} \geq |\lambda_{n}|$ with equality only when $G$ is bipartite.